# What are brooding hens called in Korean?

Tags: word-usage, dialects

The book *Fangyan* by Yang Xiang says:

> 北燕朝鮮洌水之間謂伏雞曰抱

roughly: Northern Yan and Korea call “brooding hens” *bao*

I know some Chinese dialects still use this term today.

How about Korean? Does the term 抱 still show up in any Korean languages when referring to brooding hens?

Comment: 북연 조선 열수 지간 위복 난왈포 is the Korean for that phrase. it appears to have to do with two countries, Josun (archaic Korea) and North Yun (probably Mongolia) that had a river (열수) that divided them but they constantly were fighting. there appears to be no modern, known phrase for this in learned, Korean elder circles.

Comment: According to this map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sixteen_Kingdoms_416_AD.jpg it would go to stand that Northern Yan occupied part of modern day Liaoning - Perhaps Joseon had areas up to modern day dalian and shenyang? Where the Bohai sea cuts through some of the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be a stretch to say that *Korean* would have a term for hens that shares origins with **抱**.

1. **北燕朝鮮洌水之間** talks about a region roughly corresponding to modern day Liaodong, conquered from Gojeoson by the State of Yan. This war happened around 400 years before *Fangyan* was written. This means that the people living there would have about 400 years to change to a Sinitic language, if they even spoke an early form of Korean at all.
2. **抱** (to *carry something by the arms*), and the original Chinese meaning for *brooding hens* (**孵**), both have Sino-Tibetan etymologies, i.e. they come from a geographical region at around what is now southwestern China. A dialectical word for *brooding hens* should originate from Northeastern China.
3. The modern word for chicken in Korean is **닭**, which does not resemble 抱 in meaning or sound. If we treat 抱 as a phonetic loan for something that originally meant *brooding hens*, we should look for it in a language that was spoken near Liaodong, and Tungustic languages would be more suitable.
4. The [global lexicostatistical database](http://starling.rinet.ru/new100/main.htm) proposes a Proto-Altaic root ***p`i̯ani** for the meaning *chicken*, with a Manchu descendant **f́oxa** (*chicken*) and Korean descendant **병아리** (*chick/baby chicken*). If you really want to connect 抱 (for specifically the meaning of *brooding hens*) and 병아리, we could say that they may both be derived from a language spoken around the Liaodong peninsula which had a word for *chicken* that is also ancestral to Manchu *f́oxa*, which has an initial that phonetically matches  抱. This interpretation is probably grasping at straws and is most likely untrue.
5. You will probably get a better answer at Linguistics StackExchange.